# array index increments a[k] = val[i++];

Tags: arrays, c, loops, indexing

Is this proper way of assigning values?

```cpp
    int a[n], val[n]; 
    int i = 0, k = 0;
 
    while (i < n && k < n) 
    { 
        a[k] = val[i++];
        k++;
    }
```

I am trying to assign `val[i]` to `a[k]` and increment `i++` in the same line, does this have any undefined behavior or is this a bad practice?

Comment: The expression `int a[n]` is not valid C++, so the assignment is Undefined Behavior.  For runtime arrays, use `std::vector`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews what about in c ?

Comment: There wouldn't be anything wrong with `a[k++] = val[i++];` in any but the most rigid of ideologies. All of the variables in play are independent so there won't be any unexpected results. Unless your expectations are wrong. Something like `a[i] = val[i++];`, using `i` twice with one increment, would lead to problems. When does it increment? This is actually well-defined but the answer might surprise you.

Comment: In general it's best to make your code as clear as possible, and combining the increment with the copy might make that unclear. You have no need for `k` since they're meant to be equal (and cover the same `[0,n)` interval), so just a basic `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) a[i] = val[i];`

Comment: @DilipKumar valid in C, but not always supported by compilers. Consult the compiler documentation or [Check the feature support macro](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array#Variable-length_arrays) to confirm support.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Re “The expression int a[n] is not valid C++”: You do not know what `n` is. It could be some form of constant. And that is a declaration, not an expression. For the purposes of a question like this, `n` is merely a generic placeholder used for convenience of illustration and is not relevant to the question.

Comment: @Dilip Kumar It is unclear why there are used two indices when their ranges are equal.:)

Comment: You really want `size_t i = 0, k = 0;`...

Comment: The array `val` has not been initialised, so the result of copying it is *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: @Weather: The values of the elements of `val` are indeterminate, and using them does not have undefined behavior since the array cannot be declared `register`.

Answer (score 2):

The posted code has defined behavior provided `n` is positive and reasonably small to not cause a *Stack overflow*.

Be aware that `i` and `n` should have the same type to avoid conversion issues, such as undefined behavior if `n` has type `size_t` with a value beyond the range of `int`.  Such a case would almost certainly cause undefined behavior when defining the huge VLA anyway.

Note that you could increment both index variables in the same expression:

```
    int a[n], val[n]; 
    int i = 0, k = 0;
 
    while (i < n && k < n) { 
        a[k++] = val[i++];
    }
```

Note that using a `for` loop and a single index variable is much simpler and less error prone:

```
    int a[n], val[n]; 
 
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
        a[i] = val[i];
    }
```

Note however that the elements of `val` must have been initialized fore the loop to avoid undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can increment both

```
   a[k++] = val[i++];
```

2. `for(...)` are better for this job.

Comment: thanks, agree  for point 2 this is a sample example of much larger program

Comment: @DilipKumar the example needs to be representative of the actual problem you face or you will get answers like this that are 100% correct and 100% useless to you.